# Kannel bearer box rejecting message from fakesmsc

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, kannel

I get the message 
`2013-07-31 17:30:59 [16256] [6] WARNING: smsc_fake: invalid message syntax from client, ignored` at the bearebox when I try to send message from the fakesmsc. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem was caused when I was using the fakesmsc in interactive mode. I was sending the messages in an **incorrect format**. I.e just typing the message instead of typing `"FROM TO text message+to+send"`, for instance. The user guide gives examples of correct formatting.